# How can I follow the player sprite with the camera?

Tags: xna

I've spent the last 4 days trying to figure out how to get a camera to follow the player sprite. I've followed every tutorial I could find and none of them worked.

My Camera script looks like this.

```
namespace CameraTest
{
    public class Camera2D
    {
        #region Fields

        protected float _zoom;
        protected Matrix _transform;
        protected Matrix _inverseTransform;
        protected Vector2 _pos;
        protected float _rotation;
        protected Viewport _viewport;
        protected MouseState _mState;
        protected KeyboardState _keyState;
        protected Int32 _scroll;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public float Zoom
        {
            get { return _zoom; }
            set { _zoom = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Camera View Matrix Property
        /// </summary>
        public Matrix Transform
        {
            get { return _transform; }
            set { _transform = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Inverse of the view matrix, can be used to get objects screen coordinates
        /// from its object coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public Matrix InverseTransform
        {
            get { return _inverseTransform; }
        }
        public Vector2 Pos
        {
            get { return _pos; }
            set { _pos = value; }
        }
        public float Rotation
        {
            get { return _rotation; }
            set { _rotation = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public Camera2D(Viewport viewport)
        {
            _zoom = 1.0f;
            _scroll = 1;
            _rotation = 0.0f;
            _pos = Vector2.Zero;
            _viewport = viewport;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Update the camera view
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            //Call Camera Input
            Input();
            //Clamp zoom value
            _zoom = MathHelper.Clamp(_zoom, 0.0f, 10.0f);
            //Clamp rotation value
            _rotation = ClampAngle(_rotation);
            //Create view matrix
            _transform =    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) * 
                            Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_zoom, _zoom, 1)) * 
                            Matrix.CreateTranslation(_pos.X, _pos.Y, 0);
            //Update inverse matrix
            _inverseTransform = Matrix.Invert(_transform);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example Input Method, rotates using cursor keys and zooms using mouse wheel
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void Input()
        {
            _mState = Mouse.GetState();
            _keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            //Check zoom
            if (_mState.ScrollWheelValue > _scroll)
            {
                _zoom += 0.1f;
                _scroll = _mState.ScrollWheelValue;
            }
            else if (_mState.ScrollWheelValue < _scroll)
            {
                _zoom -= 0.1f;
                _scroll = _mState.ScrollWheelValue;
            }
            //Check rotation
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                _rotation -= 0.1f;
            }
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                _rotation += 0.1f;
            }
            //Check Move
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                _pos.X += 0.5f;
            }
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                _pos.X -= 0.5f;
            }
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                _pos.Y += 0.5f;
            }
            if (_keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                _pos.Y -= 0.5f;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clamps a radian value between -pi and pi
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="radians">angle to be clamped</param>
        /// <returns>clamped angle</returns>
        protected float ClampAngle(float radians)
        {
            while (radians < -MathHelper.Pi)
            {
                radians += MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            while (radians > MathHelper.Pi)
            {
                radians -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            return radians;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And I've been running the update function from the Game1 class but it does nothing.

```
camera.Update();
```

Is it even possible to do a camera that follows the player with XNA 4.0?

Comment: This really shouldn't be too hard, and there are plenty of working tutorials available. The basic gist of a solution is: update your camera's position or view target along with the player sprite's position. For this question to be 'valid' on this site, you should include some code samples of what you have tried and what exactly isn't working. As of right now, there's hardly anything we can do for you.

Comment: Well, there's [this article](http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/) for starters. Additionally, you've actually got to apply the camera matrix to the renderer for it to do anything (you didn't say if you were actually using the camera's matrix anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XNA's normal 2D graphics routines (i.e. Spritebatch) to draw your scene, a 3D camera script will not be helpful.  Instead, store your camera position and scale as Vector2s and  update your drawing code in this manner:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

spriteBatch.Draw(gameObject.texture, (gameObject.location - cameraOffset) * cameraScale, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, cameraScale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow an object I would recommend using Lerp and setting the camera's position to to your player object.  You can achieve this by doing something like:

```
camera.Pos = Vector2.Lerp(camera.Pos, player.Position);
```

This should follow your player in a smoothly.